# Getting error while triong to push all my project code into bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am getting the following error while trying to push my first project into bit bucket repository.

> Error:

```
To https://subhrajyoti@bitbucket.org/subhrajyoti/oditek_project.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://subhrajyoti@bitbucket.org/subhrajyoti/oditek_project.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

I was following the below steps to push all my project code into bit-bucket repository.

```
1-git init
2-git add -A
3-git commit -m "Initial Commit"
4-git status
5-git remote add origin https://subhrajyoti@bitbucket.org/subhrajyoti/oditek_project.git
6-git push -u origin master
```

Here I need to push all my code to bit-bucket repository. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do a git pull before you can do a push. Your remote repository has changes your local does not have

```
git pull
```

If you branch is not set to the upstream master you'll have to run this command too

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master master
```

[Git pull documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull)

Comment: Can you please say after which point i have to run this command.?

Comment: You have to run it before git push -u origin master

Comment: Ok,let me to test and let you know.

Comment: `To https://subhrajyoti@bitbucket.org/subhrajyoti/oditek_project.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://subhrajyoti@bitbucket.org/subhrajyoti/oditek_project.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.`

Comment: What was your output from git pull?

Comment: ` no common commits
remote: Counting objects: 6, done
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done
remote: Total 6 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (6/6), done.
From https://bitbucket.org/subhrajyoti/oditek_project
 * [new branch]      master     -> origin/master
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details
    git pull <remote> <branch>
If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:
    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> master
`

Comment: The above was the output from git pull.

Comment: Okay run this command and then do a git push. git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master master

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144560/discussion-between-subhra-and-colwin).